# Switch to Finder not showing windows

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, finder

When I switch to the Finder using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, no open Finder windows show up.

I switched to finder with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, Finder is brought to the front, but its windows are not.

Answer (score 0):

The Finder stays "open" even if windows are not open/present, and when switching to the Finder icon via *cmd+tab* and no windows show, press *cmd+ n* and a finder window will open/appear.

So, if you have no *finder windows* open, when switching to the finder app using *cmd+tab*, it will do nothing, besides being *active* (check menu bar and you will see Finder menu options), which allows you to press *cmd+n* to open a new window.  Once windows are open, using *cmd+tab* will switch to any open window. Same goes for most applications as well, ie: Firefox, Safari, etc..

Comment: Thanks, but I always use cmd+tab to switch among apps. But I don't know why, now I can't switch to a finder window already open with this short cut. The finder window stays open, but doesn't appear with cmd+tab.

Comment: interesting. do you have any hacks or other aps running that interfere with the default functionality of the finder? Trying removing your com.apple.finder.plist file, and see if that does the trick.